# PrimeFaces get the current page number on page change event

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, datatables

I have a [primefaces datatable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf).
 I need to know the current page number on `page change event` using client side API.

I am using,

```
<p:ajax event="page" oncomplete="myFunction(usersWidget);"/>
```

Inside myFunction() i have

```
debugger;
console.log(usersWidget.paginator.getCurrentPage());
```

The problem is, callbacks inside `oncomplete` of page event are called before the new page is  set `(PrimeFaces.widget.Paginator.setPage)` on the paginator.  I traced this with the debugger.

That being said, i would get the previous page number i was on and not the current page number, inside oncomplete callback.

If i could get a callback after the page is set after i click the page link, i would know the current page.

**EDIT:** Docs say that its a callback called after ajax completion and after DOM is UPDATED. 
then what could be potentially wrong?

Pointers please?

Answer (score 2):

Its strange , cause oncomplete being called after the page was updated...

How about calling `oncomplete="myFunction();"` **without** passing the parameter ?

You might be passing the old object (with outdated information) that way... the usersWidget is global variable anyway... ans should be present in your js file

Since it seems that client side api is not synced with the right values

As a workaround you could try to pass the page value from server like this

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) 
     FacesContext
         .getCurrentInstance()
         .getViewRoot()
         .findComponent("someOformID:someTableId");
```

or try, instead of the line above,

```
PageEvent.getPage(); //PageEvent is an argument to you listener
myPageHolder = dataTable.getPage();
```

Than place this value to bean property and put it inside some hidden value in xhtml , than update that hidden value with `p:ajax update` and access it from within js

Comment: thnx for your answer first of all. yes widget war will be a global object. So even if i don't pass it to the function and use it as a global object there should not be any difference. yes, its strange. i will try it though

Comment: Also, just FYI, when i print the object in the console and look inside the tree it shows correct value. this was bit confusing. so i putted a break point and checked that inside myFunction i don't have updated value yet. its after the myFunction completes i see the updated value in console.

Comment: Same behavior with the approach u suggested of not passing the object and using it as a global object. Hope i was able to explain my problem properly.

Comment: looks like a bug :/ open an issue or ask on primefaces forum... anyway as a temp (bad) solution you can parse `subscribersexTable.paginator.currentReport` and extract the page number from its text... for example `usersWidget.paginator.currentReport[0].innerText`

Comment: the currentReport is also updated after myFunction or callback inside oncomplete has finished execution that is before `PrimeFaces.widget.Paginator.setPage` i believe. I will check it again though. Thnx @Daniel. Do post if you get anything on the problem.

Comment: @Mashit , You are right , haven't noticed it shows the outdated text, I posted a possible workaround... take a look.

Comment: Though server interaction should not be required, i will look into the workaround, you have mentioned. thnx

Comment: @Mashit You could check if your client side solution worked fine on versions prior to 3.4 in which datatable was heavily re written (I think) , and if so , open an issue...

Comment: Well i usually have multiple data-tables in a page. so keeping multiple hidden values would be difficult to manage. i would rather update the contents of the widget object, the client side object itself. don't know exactly how would i do that, but this should be better.

Comment: I've the same problem but also the work-around provides me the previous page and not the target page